# Create new contract from Relay

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Currently I import a contract into another one, wich allow me to create a new contract based on the imported one. 
I would like to manage versions of the imported contract, so a RelayContract (or RegistryContract) seems fine, I will reference the address of the last version of my contract in this Relay, but how do I then create a new contract based of this last version ?

My code :

```
import "Contract.sol";

contract ContractFactory {
  contractAddress = new Contract();
  Contract(contractAddress).someFunction();
}
```

Instead of this, I would like use a relay like this :

```
contract ContractRelay {
  address public contractAddress;

  function setPotContractAddress (address _contractAddress) public {
    contractAddress = _contractAddress;
  }
}
```

To get the address of the last version of the contract and then create a new one.

Thank you